# Does the 'auto' keyword know when to use a const iterator?

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, vector, auto

If you're looping through a container as such:

```
typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>> Container;
Container container;

for(Container::const_iterator element = container.begin(); element != container.end(); element++)
{
    //Read through values
}
```

And instead of using the typedef you decide to use auto:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>> container;

for(auto element = container.begin(); element != container.end(); element++)
{
    //Read through values
}
```

Assuming you don't alter the values, does the auto keyword use a const iterator over a non const one?

This question is curiosity more than anything, the only reason I can see this being an applicable question in a real life scenario would be if you needed to communicate that you weren't to alter values to another person working on the code.

Comment: Erm, that's not correct code even without `auto`. You have to initialize variables before you use them or face UB. If you fix that and initialize it, it will become whatever the type of the initializing expression is (basically). If you want explicit const iteration, use `cbegin`/`cend`; else `begin`/`end`.

Comment: So sorry for not being immensely thorough about initializing the container.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clearer. The container is fine; the iterator is what is uninitialized. Uninitialized iterators are in states such that using them is undefined. I didn't downvote btw.

Comment: Container::const_iterator element = container.begin();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Use `cbegin` and `cend` to be explicit about using const iterator.

2) `begin()` and `end()` return `const_iterator` when method is declared as `const`

Comment: Thanks wasn't aware of cbegin and cend

Comment: Alternatively use the range-based for, and bind the value with a const reference: `for (const auto& element : container) {…}`