# How does the 'auto' keyword know when to use a const_iterator matching function overloads?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, auto, overloading

I understand the content of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692681/does-the-auto-keyword-know-when-to-use-a-const-iterator) but how do things work when function overloads are used?

For instance in `std::map` the following methods are defined:

```
      iterator find (const key_type& k);
const_iterator find (const key_type& k) const;
```

How is it possible to pick one or the other using the `auto` keyword? Something like the following does not seem correct to me:

```
auto i = mymap.find(key);        //calls the non-const method?
const auto i = mymap.find(key);  //calls the const method?
```

Comment: That's too late, the LHS isn't involved in overload resolution.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Are you saying that it doesn't even work using `const_iterator i = mymap.find(key);`? So what's the point of having that function overload?

Comment: `auto it = as_const(map).find(...);`

Comment: @DarioP That works because `iterator` is convertible to `const_iterator`, it calls the non-const overload. The const overload is used, when `mymap` itself is const.

Comment: @Xeo is that something standard? And would it's usage be advised by the typical const-correctness rules?

Comment: @stijn I've found something similar here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518894/forcing-use-of-cbegin-cend-in-range-based-for

Comment: @stijn Nope, not standard, just a convenience function with an obvious implementation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deduced type of "auto it = unordered\_map.find(key)"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365233/deduced-type-of-auto-it-unordered-map-findkey)

Answer (score 3):

```
std::map<int, int> mutable_map;
const std::map<int, int> const_map;

mutable_map.find(1); // returns iterator
const_map.find(1);   // returns const_iterator
```

You would not want to return a regular iterator from a constant `map` because that would undermine the constness. So the only way to have a `find` member function that works sensibly with constant `map`s is to have a `const` overload that returns a `const_iterator`.

Comment: The point is that you may want a `const_iterator` with a mutable map. So the possibilities are the implicit conversion or the function: `template<typename T> constexpr const T &as_const(T &t) { return t; }` used to obtain a const reference on the fly at compile time that will return the const_iterator.

Answer (score 1):

In c++14, you will have [cbegin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [cend](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) to enforce a const_iterator getter.

To do the same with the map's find methods, you need const_cast but the syntax is horrible or a small helper.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template <typename T> T const &  ccast( T const & v )  { return v; }
template <typename T> T const && ccast( T const && v ) { return v; }

int main() {
    using Map = std::map<int,int>;
    Map map;

    static_assert( std::is_same< decltype(map.find(1)), Map::iterator >::value, " mutable map give mutable iterator" );
    static_assert( std::is_same< decltype(const_cast<Map const&>(map).find(1)), Map::const_iterator >::value, "const map give imutable iterator" );

    static_assert( std::is_same< decltype(ccast(map).find(1)), Map::const_iterator >::value, "const map give imutable iterator" );
    static_assert( std::is_same< decltype(ccast(std::move(map)).find(1)), Map::const_iterator >::value, "const map give imutable iterator" );
}
```

But for a map, calling the mutable find and storing as a const iterator at the assignment is the simplest, note that it will prevent iterating from it after that

```
auto const it = map.find(1);
it++ // compilation error
std::for_each( it, end(map), /**/ ); // compilation error too
```

Comment: I've already used cbegin and cend even in c++11, maybe they are just aliases. It looks that you are making it way too complicate. Once you define your `& ccast` then you can just use it `auto it = ccast(map).find(...);` The rvalue reference looks useless in this case. Finally if you call `auto const it = map.find(1);` you will not get a `const_iterator` (that cannot change the item value) but a `const iterator` (that cannot change the pointed item).

Comment: @DarioP The rvalue reference version is for completeness, it do not change the result here, but on an object with method overloads based on the reference type, it matters. `struct A { int foo()&; int foo()&&; }`.

Comment: @DarioP And was just day dreaming on the const_iterator magic cast…

Comment: `const iterator` != `const_iterator`. The former is akin to `T* const`, while the latter is `T const*`.